# Last value and current changed value of UISlider

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uislider

I have added one UISlider to my view and given method for UIControlEventvaluechanged since i want to update my UILabel value. But i want the last changed value of the slider so that when user finally selects the value of slider i can call a method and pass the value to it.

Comment: I see no question, here.

Comment: you can create a mutable copy of the value to some other variable before assigning the new value to the current label.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  - (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {  
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", slider.value];
  }
```